# npm ERR! URI malformed while doing npm link

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-package, npm-link

I have created a local package and did `npm init -y` inside the directory `~/Desktop/0.1%/MyApp/MyPackage`. The `package.json` file looks like this -

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

After this, when I'm doing `npm link` I'm getting this error in console-

npm ERR! URI malformed

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-17T17_34_38_307Z-debug-0.log

I have installed latest version of both Node[v18.18.2] and NPM [10.2.0]

Please help me out!

I have updated Latest versions of both Node and NPM to resolve this but no luck!